# Managing quartz jobs from different web based application

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have a core java application which is using Quartz 2.2.1 with JDBC job store. All the jobs are scheduled in the same.

I am building another Spring based application using Appfuse, maven and Quartz.
I want to reschedule the jobs running in the former application from the spring application.
While doing that I am getting class not found exception as I have not added the job classes in the class path.If I am adding them I am able to update the jobs.

Is there any way to manage the jobs from Spring application without adding the job classes in the class path.

I do not want to update the quartz database using jdbc or hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is a known limitation of the Quartz remote API. It becomes very painful if you have to communicate with or manage multiple Quartz scheduler versions remotely.  It becomes even more painful when the management application uses the Quartz API internally (which seems to be your case).

If you take a look at the [QuartzDesk](https://www.quartzdesk.com) project that I founded, you will find out that it very elegantly solves the problem by exposing a JAX-WS SOAP interface through which you can communicate with and manage external Quartz scheduler instances. It hides all Quartz scheduler API complexities and Quartz differences behind a simple Quartz-like API.

The JAX-WS interface is described [here](https://www.quartzdesk.com/documentation/features#quartzanywhere-ws) and there is also the relevant WSDL file available for download.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
But can you suggest me any other way to solve this problem.

Comment: You may want to try the JMX API. This does not necessarily require the presence of the Qartz API on your application's classpath, however, there are two gotchas you will have to tackle. (1) The JMX  API is very limitted when it comes to trigger manipulation, e.g. you cannot use it to obtain trigger-specific attributes (e.g. the cron expression or a CronTrigger etc.). (2) You will need to implement custom JMX data converters in your app. As a starting point you can clone Quartz converters (see org.quartz.core.jmx stuff) and modify them to use your data model. It is quite a lot of work...